# sacar consulta sql

Tags: sql

Hola buenos dias y espero vuestra ayuda. Necesito sacar de la tabla

restaurante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

, de la tabla
usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de la tabla tipo_usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todos aquellos restaurantes que no pertenezcan a un tipo_usuario de id= 1 (propietario) en este caso es el 3 ( de nombre restaurante vacio), porque como podréis comprobar en la tabla usuario los id_restaurante de cada usuario es o 1 o 2 sobre todo los relacionados con el tipo_usuario 1(propietario).

Yo hace tiempo que toco poco las consultas y me gustaria que alguien me ayude

Comment: Que llevas hecha de tu query? la idea es ayudar con lo que se lleva, no realizarte el trabajo

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los restaurantes que no  pertenezcan a un tipo_usuario de id = 1 en SQL server, sería algo como:

SELECT a.* 
FROM restaurante a 
INNER JOIN usuario b ON a.id = b.id_restaurante
WHERE b.id_tipo_usuario <> 1

Cualquier duda o consulta, estamos a la orden, saludos.